# Conditional regex in model validation

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

I am new to regex and am validating a phone number. If the phone number starts with 011. The number can be greater than 10 digits. If it doesn't start with 011 it must be between 10-15 digits. Currently I have `(?(011)\d{10, 15}|\d{7,})` but that is not working. I know I am missing something just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
"(011\d{7,}|\d{10,15})"
```

Assumes you don't want to allow any non-digits, and that numbers beginning with `011` must be at least 10 digits long.

If not using a `ValidationExpression` you may have to anchor the pattern with `^` and `$`.

Comment: Good call. Not sure why I got caught up on the if. Thank you.